# UICollectionViewCell layout with multi line labels and image view breaks layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently trying to accomplish the following layout inside an `UICollectionViewCell`

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌─────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │              Image              │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ │                                 │ │
│ └─────────────────────────────────┘ │
│ ┌─────────────────────────────────┐ │
│ │┌───────────────────────────────┐│ │
│ ││        Multiline text         ││ │
│ │└───────────────────────────────┘│ │
│ │┌───────────────────────────────┐│ │
│ ││        Multiline text         ││ │
│ │└───────────────────────────────┘│ │
│ └─────────────────────────────────┘ │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

For that purpose I subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and create my layout using auto layout.

```swift
// MARK: - View
class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    // MARK: - UI Properties    
    private lazy var imageView = UIImageView().with {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    }
   
    private lazy var productNameLabel = UILabel().with {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.textColor = .label
        
        $0.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        
        $0.numberOfLines = 0
        $0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    }
    
    private lazy var productDescriptionLabel = UILabel().with {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        $0.textColor = .secondaryLabel
        
        $0.numberOfLines = 0
        $0.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    }
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not happening")
    }
}

// MARK: - View Setup
extension ProductCell {
    private func setupView() {
    
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        contentView.addSubview(productNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(productDescriptionLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),

            productNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            productNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            productNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            
            productDescriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            productDescriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            productDescriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            productDescriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

The `with` extension is just a convenience method to make creation of `UIViews` more clean. I already tried several configurations and/or auto layout configurations but I cannot find a solution where both labels will have multiline support and the image is still visible.

So what I want to achieve is that the image can shrink if the two labels needs more space in case of more lines in the labels. Furthermore the labels should always be visible. With the configuration you can see in the snippet I can only achieve the following result. I made the background of the cell `.systemTeal` to indicate that there are the 2 labels underneath the image.

[image]

This is achieved by adding some dummy data to do some debugging

```swift
// MARK: - View configuration
extension ProductCell {
    func configure() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "test_image_2")
        
        productNameLabel.text = "This is a ridicoulus long text lets see what is happening"
        productDescriptionLabel.text = "This is a ridicoulus long text lets see what is happening"
    }
}
```

When I have a look at the runtime issues of Xcode it tells me

```
Layout Issues: Height is ambiguous for UIImageView.

Layout Issues: Height and vertical position are ambiguous for UILabel - This is a ridiculous long text lets see what is happening.

Layout Issues: Height and vertical position are ambiguous for UILabel - This is a ridicoulus long text lets see what is happening.
```

I understand that the layout system seems to not have enough information to properly determine the height of the two labels but I am out of ideas why it lacks these information.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: try setting lower heightPriority for image height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setContentCompressionResistancePriority func to set content priority for UIlabel and UIImage.
`productNameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.init(900), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal) productDescriptionLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.init(900), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal) imageView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.init(200), for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.horizontal)`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well this is an example of how your code look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    
    return cell
 }
}
```

This is you custom cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

let label1: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.text = "Multiline 1\nMultiline1 second line"
    l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    l.textColor = .black
    l.textAlignment = .center
    l.backgroundColor = .clear
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    l.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    return l
}()

let label2: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.text = "Multiline 2\nMultiline1 second line"
    l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
    l.textColor = .black
    l.textAlignment = .center
    l.backgroundColor = .clear
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    l.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    return l
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    myImageView.backgroundColor = .red
    myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2])
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 8
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    myImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    myImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

This is the result

[image]